# Convert a string of numbers to an array in Java, where each number is a different slot

Tags: java, arrays, string

Suppose I have a string of `123456789`. I would like to split this string and each number goes in a different slot in the array. I can't use the `split()` method because there is nothing to split on. How would I accomplish this in Java.

Comment: is it compelsory that the data will be of single digit ?

Comment: Yes, it will always be a single digit.

Comment: then `toCharArray()` method will work for you of `String` class

Comment: Just as a side note: you _could_ split on an empty string (`"1234"split("");`), however, you'd get each character _plus_ an empty string at the start. That's just for the record and I'd also suggest using the `toCharArray()` approaches suggested here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int x=123456789;
char[] array = x.toString().toCharArray();

int intarray[] = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
}
```

And after this you `intarray` will be array of your numbers.
If your integer can be negative too, you must take it's absolute value and make same operations, and after that multiple first array value by `-1`. But I guess, it's not needed.

**EDIT:**

I think, I don't understand your question properly. If you want to split only string, you must use this lines only. I wrote about integers,which might be helpful too.

```
string x="123456789";
char[] array = x.toCharArray();
```

Comment: +1 for the most complete solution so far. Just to note: if you're sure the string only contains digits, this would be sufficient: `intarray[i] = array[i] - '0';`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only dealing with non-negative integers, the [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method should be suitable for you. It gives you the string as an array.

Answer (score 3):

The String class has a neat method for doing this, [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to avoid creating Strings.

```
long x = x;
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(18);
if (x == 0) {
    bb.put((byte) 0);
} else {
    while (x > 0) {
        bb.put((byte) (x % 10));
        x /= 10;
    }
}
int len = bb.position();
byte[] digits = new byte[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    digits[i] = bb.get(len - i - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

is it compelsory that the data will be of single digit ?If the data may come in multiple digits then it will not be possible to identify whether the numeric value is of single digit of multiple digit ?
e.g. if it is 12(twelve) then if all string is 512 then how will you identify whether to represent 512 as 5,1,2 or 5,12 ?
if it is fix that the numbers will be in single digits and non negetives then `toCharArray()` of `String` class will work for you

Comment: No, the entire string represents only one number

Comment: Then,

`int x=123456789;
char[] array = x.toString().toCharArray();
int intarray[] = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
}` will work for you

Comment: Instead of putting that much code in a comment I'd suggest editing your answer. It will be easer to read the better formatted code there.